# How to save audio files and send them

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm trying to save an audio file to send it to whatsapp, but i am unable to save it on external storage. I am not getting where am I making mistakes.

I am using this code:

```
FileOutputStream outputStream;
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES), "FUNG");
if (!file.mkdirs()) {}
try {
   outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
   outputStream.write(R.raw.badum2);
   outputStream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES) + "/FUNG/badum2.m4a");
shareIntent.setType("audio/m4a");
shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

When the file is sent to WhatsApp, it shows error like:

> "fail to share, please try again"

I don't see the audio file in directory, so I guess the error is that I am making some mistakes in saving audio files on external storage.

Please help me in solving this.

Comment: Did you request the permission to write external storage in your manifest file AND at runtime (the latter only in android 6 and above)?

Comment: yes, i put the permission on manifest, permission to android 6 and check if has an external storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see multiple problems:

(1) `if (!file.mkdirs()) {}` creates a directory at the path of file, later you use that directory to open an output stream, which of course does not work.

Solution:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES), "FUNG/badum2.m4a"); // assumed target file
if (!file.getParentFile().mkdirs() && !file.getParentFile().isDirectory()) {
     // Abort! Directory could not be created!
}
```

(2) `outputStream.write(R.raw.badum2);` will write the int value referring 
to your resource, not the resource itself.

Solution:

Use `InputStream in = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.badum2);` where ctx is a Context instance (e.g. your Activity) and write its content to the file.

```
try {
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    try {
        InputStream in = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.badum2);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) >= 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    outputStream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What I do with this "in"?  because it don't save anything

Comment: If you don't want to save anything, what is the purpose of `file` and `outputStream`?

Comment: I want save, because only is possible send a audio file to wpp if it is on external storage. But i dont know what do with this "in" to save it

Comment: Updated my answer, this should copy your resource file to `<RINGTONES>/FUNG/badum2.m4a`

Comment: continue without save a file (I change int to byte because was required)

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. So it's still not working? Do you get exceptions or an error message?

Comment: No, the error was mine, I forget of change a directory file. Now working fine. Thx :D